# Static files are not loading in Django. Get 404 error. Static directry defination in settings.py looks proper

Tags: python, django, static

**I get the following error;**

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
.
.
.
so on...

**URL setting in settings.py is as follows;**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

**I have entered the static file urls in the template(home.html);**

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>
  <!-- meta data -->
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/logo4.png' %}" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="Website Builder Description">
  
  
  <title>home.html</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'tether/tether.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dropdown/css/style.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'animatecss/animate.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'theme/css/style.css' %}">
```

**My folder structure as follows:**

[image]

[image]

Can some one help me to resolve the issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

STATICFILES_DIR is not correct it is STATICFILES_DIRS (DIR with an S at the end so it must be plural as well)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py the DEBUG is set to TRUE

```
DEBUG = True
```

I have all the static files in 'static' folder(i have verified the file path in static filder, its in order), so Django should find the static files.

Below is the complete code of my templates/home.html

```
{%load static%}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  >
<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="generator" content="Mobirise v4.12.4, mobirise.com">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'images/logo4.png' %}" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="description" content="Website Builder Description">
    
  <title>home.html</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'web/assets/mobirise-icons/mobirise-icons.css' %}">  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'tether/tether.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'dropdown/css/style.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'animatecss/animate.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'theme/css/style.css' %}">
  <link rel="preload" as="style" href="{% static 'mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css' %}"><link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/mobirise/css/mbr-additional.css" type="text/css">
  
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <section class="menu cid-s5iISe2c23" once="menu" id="menu1-8">

    

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand beta-menu navbar-dropdown align-items-center navbar-fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm bg-color transparent">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div class="menu-logo">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <span class="navbar-logo">
                    <a href="home.html">
                         <img src="{% static 'images/logo-1-478x122.png' %}" alt="Mobirise" title="" style="height: 3.8rem;">
                         
                    </a>
                </span>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-dropdown nav-right" data-app-modern-menu="true"><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="https://mobirise.co" aria-expanded="true">
                        
                        About Us
                    </a></li></ul>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>

<section class="engine"><a href="https://mobirise.info/o">free portfolio website templates</a></section><section class="header1 cid-s5hTifxxmG" id="header16-6">

    

    

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-10 align-center">
                
                <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle mbr-light pb-3 mbr-fonts-style display-2">Work and select</h3>
                
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>

<section class="features3 cid-s5hXWwfo5o" id="features3-7">

    

    
    <div class="container">
        <div class="media-container-row">
            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                            Engineers</h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-4">Work And many more..</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mbr-section-btn text-center"><a href="https://mobirise.co" class="btn btn-success display-4">Sign up or Login</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6">
                <div class="card-wrapper">
                    
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-5">
                            Companies and recruiters</h4>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style display-4">Select and more...<br><br><br><br><br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mbr-section-btn text-center"><a href="https://mobirise.co" class="btn btn-primary display-4">
                            Sign up or Login</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            

            
        </div>
    </div>
</section>


  <script src="{% static 'web/assets/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'popper/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'tether/tether.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'dropdown/js/nav-dropdown.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'dropdown/js/navbar-dropdown.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'touchswipe/jquery.touch-swipe.min.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'viewportchecker/jquery.viewportchecker.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'smoothscroll/smooth-scroll.js' %}"></script>
  <script src="{% static 'theme/js/script.js' %}"></script>
  
  
  <input name="animation" type="hidden">
  </body>
</html>
```

Refer the below screenshot for code and webpage loaded:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You set :

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

Which means , django will find the static file ,like png,jpg,css,js ,in assets.

But you also set:

```py
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),

]
```

Which means ,django also will find the static file ,in static,if can not find file in assets.

So,if you are sure the static file in one folder of them, you may check the setting about :

```
DEBUG = True
```

If you set the DEBUG to `False`,the app server by django would not provide static files apis.

[Django document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/deployment/) tell you how to deploying static files,use nginx ,uwsgi is OK.

Also ,you can use `serve` to  get it in urls.py (not suggest this way,in django.views.static)

```
import mimetypes
import posixpath
from pathlib import Path
from django.http import (
    FileResponse, Http404, HttpResponseNotModified
)
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, re_path,include
from django.utils._os import safe_join
from django.utils.http import http_date
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.views.static import directory_index, was_modified_since


def re_serve(request, path, document_root=None, show_indexes=False):
    path = posixpath.normpath(path).lstrip('/')
    fullpath = Path(safe_join(document_root, path))
    if fullpath.is_dir():
        if show_indexes:
            return directory_index(path, fullpath)
        raise Http404(_("Directory indexes are not allowed here."))
    if not fullpath.exists():
        raise Http404(_('“%(path)s” does not exist') % {'path': fullpath})
    # Respect the If-Modified-Since header.
    statobj = fullpath.stat()
    if not was_modified_since(request.META.get('HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'),
                              statobj.st_mtime, statobj.st_size):
        return HttpResponseNotModified()
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(str(fullpath))
    content_type = content_type or 'application/octet-stream'
    if path.split(".")[-1] == "js":
        content_type = "text/javascript" # I change it,the source code is different
    response = FileResponse(fullpath.open('rb'), content_type=content_type)
    response["Last-Modified"] = http_date(statobj.st_mtime)
    if encoding:
        response["Content-Encoding"] = encoding
    return response


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

if not settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', re_serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}, name='static'),
    ]
```

If you are sure ,both static file are in right folder and set the `DEBUG` to  `True`,may comes from other error,show more code please.